# Why does time.sleep in unrelated code location affect time.perf_counter_ns?

Tags: python, time

I am trying to use `time.perf_counter_ns` to time how long something takes in my code. It all works as expected if the code looks like this:

```
import time
total = 0
num_samples = 1000

for i in range(num_samples):
    s = time.perf_counter_ns()
    e = time.perf_counter_ns()
    total += e - s
print(total/num_samples)
```

```
$ python3 test.py 
91.507
```

However, when I add a `time.sleep(1)` in an unrelated spot in the code, the time I am measuring is higher:

```
import time
total = 0
num_samples = 1000
time.sleep(1)     # <<< I didnt think this should matter!!
for i in range(num_samples):
    s = time.perf_counter_ns()
    e = time.perf_counter_ns()
    total += e - s
print(total/num_samples)
```

```
$ python3 test.py 
417.304
```

So, why does adding a `time.sleep(1)` in a seemingly unrelated spot in the code makes a difference?

Using:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
```

Comment: Can you run each a few more times and show the results?

Comment: Just for the record, I can reproduce the results. Also ran some variants (multiple loops, different points of sleeping) and the difference consistently got larger after ``time.sleep(1)`` is run. It does not seem to be a measurement error.

Comment: I can post more results if needed, but it is pretty consistent: around 95 without the `time.sleep(1)`, around 450 with it

Comment: Also, same behavior if I replace `time.sleep(1)` with `os.system("sleep 1")`

Comment: Ok, here is a few more attempts

```python3 test.py 
493.35
python3 test.py 
441.44
python3 test.py 
506.74
python3 test.py 
559.67
python3 test.py 
552.06
```